# Unable to debug Blazor Webassembly

Tags: debugging, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have not been able to debug ever since I started using the Blazor webassembly a few weeks ago. I have looked at the ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1
and looked at some videos and All look well.  I have created a new app from scratch and still no change.

When looking at the breakboint it states : **breakpoint set but not bound yet**

On the server project it includes:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" />
```

And the launch settings profile is set with the inspectUri

```
"profiles": {
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "TestDebugging.Server": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
```

On Client project It includes:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20216.8" PrivateAssets="all" />
 <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0-preview5.20210.3" />
```

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.5.0
> VisualStudio.16.Release/16.5.0+29911.84 Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.8.03752
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> **Chrome Version**: Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Upgrade to 3.2.0

Comment: Nope Same issue after upgrade

Comment: Upgrade VS to 16.6 or 16.7-preview1

Comment: Same goes with my Blazor projects. VS constantly failing. It works after restarting VS for a while, and then stuck again.

Comment: @aguafrommars can you put your comment as the answer "Upgrade VS to 16.6" this solved my issue.

Comment: @greektreat with pleasure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade VS to 16.6 or 16.7-preview1